# Can't use NgSliderModule

Tags: angular, import, module, slider

I need a slider in my application, but I don't know what the app crash.

> Connexion:11 Error: Unexpected token <
>       Evaluating http://localhost:3000/Ng/@angular/material/slider
>       Evaluating http://localhost:3000/Scripts/app.module.js
>       Evaluating http://localhost:3000/Scripts/main.js

My app.module (I don't copy all my imports of course)

```
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';

 @NgModule({
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    RoutingModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    SiteStoreModule,
    ApplicationPipesModule,
    MatSliderModule,
],
```

My component:

```
   import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';

@Component({
selector: 'order-detail-filter',
moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: './order-detail-filter.html',
styleUrls: ["./order-detail-filter.css"],
 })
```

My html associated :

```
  <mat-slider min="1" max="5" step="0.5" value="1.5"></mat-slider>
```

Comment: are you using mat-slider in same module component or in different module component..???

Comment: No, we don't have modules for each component ( order-detail-filter.module.ts don't exist), I just import it for the moment in the main module (app.module.ts) and I want to use it in my "order-detail-filter.html"

Answer (score 0):

try to import

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule([
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
    ]
]
```